# How can I speed up development with GWT dev mode?

Tags: debugging, gwt, gwt-dev-mode

I'm experiencing very weak performance with gwt dev mode. There is virtually no difference  between normal compile and devmode. If i refresh the page without making modifications it takes about 60-80s . I have already deleted all breakpoints.
If anyone wants to experiment i am trying a very slightly altered version of geomajas archetype.

I meant devmode not superdevmode..edited

Comment: When you say normal compile you mean SuperDevMode or server´s deployment? Anyway there is something strange, because 100% sure there is big differences between DevMode and the rest of alternatives.
How big is your app?

Comment: @apanizo by normal compile i mean using right click on the project, choose  maven install and then use a runjettyrun run configuration. The app is as big as the geomajas archetype. It has lots of libs but    it has only the application entry and two entity classes as actual java source. And i'm using devmode not superdev